# Number of ways for making a set of signature list

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A meeting is being held in a big hall which has $7$ doors by which the mourners enter the hall. One can use any one of the $7$ doors to enter and can come at any time during meeting.At each door a register is kept in which a mourner has to put down his signature while entering

---

If $200$ people attend the meeting the no. Of different sets of $7$ lists that can arise

---

The problem can be solved by considering that each mourner has 7 options to choose from but the rank or order in which $200$ people sign also matters . What is an easy way to solve both the tasks I.e check the order of every mourner eith condition that each has $7$ options.

Comment: Does it matter which list the mourners sign?  If two sets are identical, except that the lists at doors $1$ and $2$ are interchanged, are the sets considered the same or different?

Comment: @saulspatz no they aren't identical

Comment: I've edited the title to spell out "number"; using "no." as an abbreviation for "number" is confusing, especially when you capitalize the following word unusually (as you did here in both the title and the body text).  (Generally, we abbreviate "number" as "no." only when it is used as an indicator of a sequence: e.g., "Number 1" $\to$ "No. 1," but "the number of ways" is generally not abbreviated.)

Comment: @BrianTung got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can arrange the mourners in a list in $200!$ ways.  Now divide the list into $7$ sections, and assign the first section to the first guest book, the second section to the second guestbook, and so on.  To split the list into $7$ sections, we need to insert $6$ dividers into the list, and there are $201$ places we can put a divider -- to the left of any person, or to the right of all the persons.  If none of the dividers could be placed in the same spot, we could say that there are $$200!\binom{201}{6}$$ possibilities, this isn't so.  We can choose the same position for a divider more than once, creating an empty list.

So, it comes down to this: how many ways are there to choose $6$ items from $201$ if the order of choosing doesn't matter and we can choose the same item more than once?  But this is stars and bars: how many ways are there to place $6$ identical balls in $201$ distinct buckets?  Therefore, the solution is $$200!\binom{206}6$$

Comment: do you mean 199 places for dividers in non-empty lists case?

Comment: @cosmo5 Yes, you're right.  I wasn't really thinking about empty lists per se, but about putting two dividers in the same place.